# Can Angular schematics read files outside the main directory?

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I want to create a file outside of the directory where the dependency for a custom schematics is (probably write a file there also)

For example:

/

/directory_1/package.json   => has the schematics dependency

/other_dir/file_to_read.txt  => this is the file i want to read

directory_1 and other_dir are on the same level.

```
const jsonStr = tree.read("../other_dir/file_to_read.txt").toString('utf-8');
```

keeps saying:

```
Path "../other_dir/file_to_read.txt" is invalid.
```